# UIScrollView placed in NIB file goes up when application starts

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, nib

I have a view with two UILabel (simulating a header and a footer) and a UIScrollView placed between them vertically:

[image: Layout in NIB file]

However, if I start the application in simulator the UIScrollView goes a few pixels up while the rest of elements remain in their position:

[image: Layout in simulator]

Is it normal that behaviour? How can I place the UIScrollView exactly at the position I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have set the scrollview to have a flexible height, but fixed bottom margin. Check the springs and struts settings for your view, found in layout page.

Comment: I double-checked it and everything seems to be normal. Could this be related to not setting the contentSize attribute?

Comment: @elitalon - No `contentSize` is only used to determine if and how far the scrollview can scroll. The screenshots still looks like something fishy is up with the layout. Do the super views have `autoresizeSubview` set?